# how to follow OSGi bundle changes

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

What's the best way to track any change in the **entire** the bundle population?

I've got some logic which scans all bundles for some bundle capabilities.

I want this to kick in only if there's a change in the bundle population, i.e. a bundle has been added/updated/removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [BundleTracker](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/BundleTracker.html). You will receive a callback on the changes.